# How can I change the default select options?

Tags: python, django

I set a selection model form at models.py and form.py. But I want the default options to change dynamically.

For example, if it has a data [user:test, status:wishlist, gameSlug:test-1] found in the database. I hope when I using this "test" account open "test-1" page, the selection will show "wishlist" as default. here is my code:

models.py:

```
class UsersMarksTags(models.Model):
    STATUS = [
         ('booked', 'Booked'),
         ('wishlist', 'Add to Wishlist'),
         ('Not interested', 'Not intersted'),
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE);
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False, choices = STATUS, default = 'booked');
    gameSlug = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False);
```

form.py:

```
class statusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UsersMarksTags;
        fields = ['status'];
```

views.py:

```
class showGameInformation(FormView):
    template_name = "showList/gameDetail.html";
    form_class = statusForm;

    def form_valid(self, form):
        .......
```

test.html:

```
<form method = 'POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class statusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UsersMarksTags;
        fields = ['status']
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(statusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['status'] = 'wishlist'
```

You can set it based on any condition if you like.

Comment: I want to change the options under views.py depends on the user's record, I will use a query string to get the result and change the default options according to the result, how should I do?

Comment: Try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values